# If an async server socket.BeginAccept() starts a new thread for each client socket assigning a new port, how do my client sockets know the port?

Tags: c#, .net

I am reading up on this microsoft async server server socket example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/fx6588te.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

```
        // Bind the listener socket object to the local endpoint and
        // listen for incoming connections.
        try {
            listener.Bind(localEndPoint); 
            listener.Listen(100);

        while (true) {
            // Set the event to nonsignaled state.
            allDone.Reset(); //allDone is a ManualResetEvent

            // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
            listener.BeginAccept( 
                new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),
                listener );

            // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.
            allDone.WaitOne();
        }
```

**Question 1:**

As new client sockets join my server socket, server starts a new thread for each client, and each server thread has **its own port number** as I understand. If thats so , how do my new clients know which port to connect to?The IP address for the server is same but the port must be changing for each new client. Yet microsoft code does no such thing in their respective async client example( at the bottom of the page above)

**Question 2:**

What if I don't use the last line i.e.
    allDone.WaitOne();
would it create a crazy infinite loop as new threads are created listening for new clients?

Thank you for your time and I will REALLY appreciate if you could elaborate a little in the answer, as the same thing said twice in different words really sinks in well:)

Comment: what's the point of having an asynchronous callback, and then wrapping it with allDone, making the whole dog and pony show completely sychronous? Is the allDone just a Microsoft typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that a new connection is created is transparent to your client - they simply get a connection when they call Connect.

Comment: Actually the code above is microsoft's , they used the .waitone ... by "hangs", do you mean "blocks"? or do you mean that the program flow moves to the next line immediately without waiting? thankyou

Comment: I did mean block - I must have had a mental one just now - I'll update, thx.

Comment: So....the Asynchronous .BeginAccept() method is actually synchronous because it blocks? My brain melted

Comment: Yes, sorry - my brain must be sugar-deprived today :/ `BeginAccept` does NOT block - that's the point of the `Begin` part, so you do need the wait.