# Start Accepting new connections before or after EndAccept()

Tags: c#, .net, asyncsocket

I have a question about at what point after a BeginAccept on a socket can I tell my listener thread that it can start accepting connections again.

This is the code I have:

```
while(!mStopWaitHandle.WaitOne(0, false)) // <-- Manual Reset event to check if the service has stopped.
{
    Logging.Debug("Waiting for a connection...");

    socket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptConnection), socket);

    mReadyToAcceptWaitHandle.WaitOne(); // <-- AutoResetEvent to block until I can continue accepting connections
}
```

then in my Async Callback:

```
private void AcceptConnection(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    mReadyToAcceptWaitHandle.Set(); // <-- Tell the listener thread to start accepting connections again

    Socket socket = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
    Socket workerSocket = socket.EndAccept(ar);

    ... handle connection on workerSocket ...
}
```

This is how they do it in the [Asynchronous Server Socket Example on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

But from what I have read `BeginAccept` is not a blocking call. The blocking call is `EndAccept`, and it blocks until there is a connection to accept.

So having the `mReadyToAcceptWaitHandle.Set();`, to tell the listener thread to keep accepting connections, before EndAccept() seems odd to me because wouldn't that just cause it to keep opening `AcceptConnection` handler threads (from what I've seen from execution, it doesn't seem to do this, but I don't know why?) that all just block on `EndAccept`?

Would it not be better to have `mReadyToAcceptWaitHandle.Set();` after `EndAccept`, so that it only deals with accepting one connection at a time, and once it has accepted, but before it actually handles the communication on the connection.

Both ways seem to work, but I want to know which one is the correct way, and whether one way will have subtle negative side effects that the other doesn't.

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`The blocking call is EndAccept, and it blocks until there is a connection to accept.`

That's not an accurate description.

`EndAccept` is called from the callback of `BeginAccept` when a connect request has been received from a client. You can call `BeginAccept` again from the `BeginAccept` callback to immediately accept another connection while establishing the (previous) connection you just received via `EndAccept` (still in the connection callback).

So it is not actually necessary to use events at all to synchronize when to accept new connections. Simply call `BeginAccept` again from the callback.

Comment: According to the remarks section of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chfa7866(v=vs.110).aspx, the EndAccept documentation, EndAccept does in fact block until there is a connection in the incoming connection queue to accept. Anyway calling BeginAccept from within the BeginAccept callback is no different to calling it from the same place as the original BeginAccept after waiting for a signal on a WaitHandle, as I am doing in my code. In fact it is cleaner my way, and allows me to do more checking for other states like service stop. In fact my way is how they do it in the MSDN example.

Comment: Also you didn't even answer my question.

Comment: While it blocks, it only does so momentarily because the callback is only invoked once there is in fact a connection to accept.

Comment: You yourself in the comments of http://stackoverflow.com/a/15557881/2709382 said that BeginAccept doesn't block.

Comment: OHHH does the AsyncCallback only get executed when there is a connection to accept, but the BeginAccept doesn't block.

Comment: I was talking about `BeginAccept` in that other post, not `EndAccept`.

Comment: Oh my bad. Can you put that in your answer and I'll accept.

Comment: I'll also revert my downvote, but can only do that once you edit. Sorry I didn't see how your original answer was answering my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56074/discussion-between-tom-heard-and-500-internal-server-error).

Comment: Why not use the Task based async API and avoid the headf*&k of APM begin/end pairs altogether? I consider them effectively deprecated... Using them is a form of masochism now.